# Moving Meshes out of a Node

Tags: mesh, outliner

I'm currently trying to move these Meshes out from under this Node_0 (armature?) so that they are directly under the Scene Collection..

Even if I create a new collection, and drag and drop the Meshes into it, they still seem intrinsically tied to the Node_0..

No duplicating meshes, or trying to use 'separate' seems to work either, and I'm still pretty new to Blender, and so I don't really know what to search for on Google..

Any ideas on what is happening here, and what I need to do in order for each mesh to be its own separate entity?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The Node_0 is an empty object. With selected mesh press Alt+P and select "Clear and keep transformation" to unparent the selected meshes.

Comment: wow it worked! the shortcut didn't work (I'm on a mac), but I found the correct option in Object Mode, under 'Parent'. Thank you so much, so much to learn about this program!